# Populate long table of 2 columns from several smaller tables

Tags: excel, vba

This seems like a simple solution that involves possibly a loop and a count, but i'm stumped as to how to write it.  I have a worksheet that has several lists/tables that are side by side that i want to merge into 1 longer table that has all of the data in only 2 columns.

The source table goes on for more 'Rotations' than just the 3 in the screenshot, and the number of rows can vary and will likely have several hundred per 'Rotation'.

I put a screenshot of what I'm hoping the summary table will look like. The source data is on a worksheet called "Protocol Summary" and the destination worksheet for the 'compiled' list is on a worksheet called "Protocol Filter".

[Source worksheet "Protocol Summary"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wjAV.png)

[Destination worksheet "Protocol Filter"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wDuq.png)

It may seem a bit strange that the excel filters are in the 'Summary' worksheet and i'm trying to make a summary worksheet called 'filters' but i assure you, with the rest of the workbook, it does make some kind of sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want unique "ev type" in the protocol filter?

Comment: Both columns 'EV TYPE' and the corresponding 'COMP' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick.

You have some tricky values in your example data, i.e.: `7E1`.
To keep the formatting of those numbers I added the line:

```
Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "A").NumberFormat = "@" 'To keep the text format if needed
```

**Code:**

```
Sub copy_values()

Dim lrow_src As Long
Dim lrow_dest As Long
Dim lcol_src As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim Source_sht As Worksheet
Set Source_sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Protocol Summary") 'Set the name of the sheet to copy from
Dim Destination_sht As Worksheet
Set Destination_sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Protocol Filter") 'Set the name of the sheet to paste to


lcol_src = Source_sht.Cells(5, Source_sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find the last column from the source sheet, looking at row 5


For i = 1 To lcol_src Step 2 'Loop from the first column to the last and consider only every second column (i.e. all columns with the name "EV TYPE")

lrow_src = Source_sht.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Source sheet for the current column

    For j = 7 To lrow_src 'Loop through each rotation, from row 7 to the last for each rotation
        lrow_dest = Destination_sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1
        Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "A").NumberFormat = "@" 'To keep the text format if needed
        'Copy and paste part
        Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "A").Value = Source_sht.Cells(j, i).Value 'Copy EV Type
        Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "B").Value = Source_sht.Cells(j, i + 1).Value 'Copy COMP
    Next j

Next i
End Sub
```

---

Alternate version 1 of copy paste part:

```
Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "A").Value = Source_sht.Cells(j, i).Value 'Copy EV Type
Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "B").Value = Source_sht.Cells(j, i + 1).Value 'Copy COMP
```

Can be written in one line to, to speed things up:

```
Destination_sht.Range(Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "A"), Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "B")).Value = _
Source_sht.Range(Source_sht.Cells(j, i), Source_sht.Cells(j, i + 1)).Value
```

---

An alternative version 2 part to copy paste part for keeping format is to use (but it's much slower):

```
Source_sht.Range(Source_sht.Cells(j, i), Source_sht.Cells(j, i + 1)).Copy
Destination_sht.Range(Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "A"), Destination_sht.Cells(lrow_dest + 1, "B")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

Comment: Thanks, would the NumberFormat line be needed if all values were already 'Text' format?

Comment: Depends on the **Protocol Filter** column where we paste the data to. If it already set to 'text" then no. The "paste = copy" formula only copy and paste values, no additional format needed.

Comment: Yes, everything is set to text at this stage, the only calculations that will be made later on will just come from simple 'count' and 'countif' statements.

Comment: Then you should be fine :).

Comment: Glad it helped you. Happy coding :)!